# Implemented property error VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm using a class that Implements from an interface. 
I want to implement a property from the interface but I'm getting error:

> Class 'ListManager' must implement 'Property Count As Integer' for interface 'IListManager(Of T)'. Implementing property must have matching 'ReadOnly' or 'WriteOnly' specifiers.

Interface:

```
Namespace Assign_1

    Public Interface IListManager(Of T)

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Return the number of items in the collection m_list
        ''' </summary>
        Property Count As Integer
End Namespace
```

Class:

```
Namespace Assign_1
    Public Class ListManager(Of T)
        Implements IListManager(Of T)

        Protected m_list As List(Of T)

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Constructor
        ''' </summary>
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New()
            m_list = New List(Of T)
        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Property to count the list
        ''' </summary>
        Public ReadOnly Property Count As Integer
            Get
                Return m_list.Count
            End Get
        End Property
End Namespace
```

Does anyone know the problem?

Comment: Either make it ReadOnly in the interface definition, remove the readonly in the class, or better yet, make it a function all way around

Comment: I tried making it ReadOnly in the interface definition, removing the readonly in the class. It didn't work. I don't understand what you mean by "making a function all way around"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be necessary to define the Interface as a generic since an interface just establishes a contract of which properties and methods are implemented.

```
Public Interface IListManager
    ReadOnly Property Count As Int32

    ' function version
    Function GetCount() As Integer
End Interface

Public Class ListMgr(Of T)
    Implements IListManager

    Private myList As List(Of T)

    Public ReadOnly Property Count As Integer Implements IListManager.Count
        Get
            Return myList.Count
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function GetCount() As Integer Implements IListManager.GetCount
        Return myList.Count
    End Function

End Class
```

If you did need the interface to be generic there is just a small change:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Count As Integer Implements IListManager(Of T).Count
```

After you type in `Implements IMyInterface` VS will add the boilerplate  property and method code when you press enter.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
Public Interface IListManager(Of T)
    ReadOnly Property count As Integer
End Interface

Public Class ListManager(Of T) : Implements IListManager(Of TabAlignment)
    Protected m_list As List(Of T)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Constructor
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        m_list = New List(Of T)
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property count As Integer Implements IListManager(Of TabAlignment).count
        Get
            Return Me.m_list.Count
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```